# mlflow sklearn log_model permission denied because obviously linux does not have a D drive

Tags: path, mlflow

I am following a tutorial from a udemy course on mlflow. There is this code:

```
import os
import warnings
import sys

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import mlflow
import mlflow.sklearn

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARN)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def eval_metrics(actual, pred):
    rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, pred))
    mae = mean_absolute_error(actual, pred)
    r2 = r2_score(actual, pred)
    return rmse, mae, r2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
    np.random.seed(40)

    # Read the wine-quality csv file from the URL
    csv_url = (
        "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv"
    )
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(csv_url, sep=";")
        
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(
            "Unable to download training & test CSV, check your internet connection. Error: %s", e
        )

    # Split the data into training and test sets. (0.75, 0.25) split.
    train, test = train_test_split(data)

    # The predicted column is "quality" which is a scalar from [3, 9]
    train_x = train.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
    test_x = test.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
    train_y = train[["quality"]]
    test_y = test[["quality"]]

    alpha = 0.5
    l1_ratio = 0.5

    with mlflow.start_run():
        
        lr = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, random_state=42)
        lr.fit(train_x, train_y)

        predicted_qualities = lr.predict(test_x)

        (rmse, mae, r2) = eval_metrics(test_y, predicted_qualities)

        print("Elasticnet model (alpha=%f, l1_ratio=%f):" % (alpha, l1_ratio))
        print("  RMSE: %s" % rmse)
        print("  MAE: %s" % mae)
        print("  R2: %s" % r2)

        mlflow.log_param("alpha", alpha)
        mlflow.log_param("l1_ratio", l1_ratio)
        mlflow.log_metric("rmse", rmse)
        mlflow.log_metric("r2", r2)
        mlflow.log_metric("mae", mae)

        tracking_url_type_store = urlparse(mlflow.get_tracking_uri()).scheme
        print(mlflow.get_tracking_uri())
        print(tracking_url_type_store)
        # Model registry does not work with file store
        if tracking_url_type_store != "file":

            # Register the model
            # There are other ways to use the Model Registry, which depends on the use case,
            # please refer to the doc for more information:
            # https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/model-registry.html#api-workflow
            mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model", registered_model_name="ElasticnetWineModel")
        else:
            mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr, "model")
```

This code works until the last line `mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lr,"model") which gives the error "Permission Error".

The error message is large but in the last line it says (when trying to make a subdirectory)

```
"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/D:'"
```

Well, obviously because I am using linux (and I suspect the teacher is using windows in her machine)
The thing is, nowhere in the code I can find that a path including "/D" has been written.
Why then is the log_model function assuming this path?

Edit: Other info, I am running this on a jupyter notebook

EDIT2:
For some reason that I cant fathom mlflow in
/mlflow/store/artifact/local_artifact_repo.py
is creating the object `class LocalArtifactRepository(ArtifactRepository)` twice, and the second time with a windows path (with "D:") and the instructor's machine path. But I can't find where this is

EDIT3: Another student suggested using

```
from mlflow import MlflowClient
 
client = MlflowClient(tracking_uri="http://localhost:4321/")
produce_MLOPS_experiment = client.create_experiment(name="MLOPS_course")
MLOPS_experiment = mlflow.set_experiment("MLOPS_course")
```

And now the error is gone but there is anew error

```
MlflowException: The configured tracking uri scheme: 'file' is invalid for use with the proxy mlflow-artifact scheme. The allowed tracking schemes are: {'https', 'http'}
```